# Get Value of Input Button When Clicked for Only One Button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

So I made this formula for my input button

```
function addTip() {
  let tip = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");

  tip.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      console.log(item.value);
    });
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="3" onClick="addTip()">
<input type="button" value="5" onClick="addTip()">
<input type="button" value="7" onClick="addTip()">
```

My problem is whenever I click on a button once, nothing happens, then I click it again and it shows in the console the value but also shows (3) because it goes through all the buttons

like this

[image]

How do I make it to where if I click on one button it will show value 3, but then if I click on the next button it will change the value to show 5 only.

Basically making a tip button option and want people to choose their tip

Comment: You're not adding listeners until the first `addTip` call which will be on the first button click (and then adding new listeners on every click after). Instead just call `addTip()` in your javascript and remove it from the `onClick` on each button. Better yet use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation#:~:text=Event%20delegation%20is%20handling%20an,on%20elements%20within%20the%20container.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding listeners until the first `addTip` call which will be on the first button click (and then adding new listeners on every click after).

Instead just call `addTip()` in your javascript and remove it from the `onClick` on each button.

```js
function addTip() {
  let tip = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");

  tip.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      console.log(item.value);
    });
  });
}

addTip(); // <-- call addTip() once in the js
```

```html
<input type="button" value="3">
<input type="button" value="5">
<input type="button" value="7">
```

#### Event delegation

A cleaner solution is to use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation#:%7E:text=Event%20delegation%20is%20handling%20an,on%20elements%20within%20the%20container.). Here using [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to check if a relevant button has been clicked and then logging the `event.target.value`.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches("input[type=button]")){
      console.log(event.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="3">
<input type="button" value="5">
<input type="button" value="7">
```

Comment: so if I have an html p tag with the id of "tip" how would I display the value using this function? I tried to put `tip = event.target.value` then create another document.getEleByID('tip') and set it to tip but it didn't update the html with the tip value

Comment: `document.getElementById('tip').textContent = event.target.value;` You need to set either the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) attribute of the retrieved element.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<input type="button" value="3">
<input type="button" value="5">
<input type="button" value="7">
<script >
    function addTip() {
      let tip = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
    
      tip.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          console.log(item.value);
        });
      });
    }
    
    addTip()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```